# How can I use flexbox to make a three column layout turn into a two column layout (when the tab is resized)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My goal is to have three responsive columns using flexbox. Currently, when resized, the columns can go left to right or up to down. I'm trying to make the three column layout go into a two column layout with the third column centered below the first two. However, the first and second columns don't go next to each other.

I google this and looked at other examples and tried to implement them, but I'm not sure why it still isn't working.

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/sbarclay7/pen/ZEQZvaj

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
    
body {
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-align: center;
}


* { box-sizing: border-box; }


.wrapper {
    padding-top:2.1rem;
    display: flex;

    padding-bottom:2.2rem;
    max-width:40%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin:auto;  
}
    
.category {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 16rem;
    flex: 1; 
    background-color:#203a8a;
    border-radius: 0.7rem;
    border: 1.5px solid rgb(5, 30, 37);
    
    }
     
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
     

@media (max-width: 1000px) { 
    .wrapper {
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-flow: column wrap;

    }
    .category {
        width: 49%;
    }
  }


  @media (max-width: 700px) { 
    .wrapper {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .category {
        width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper flex">
        
        <div class="category" style="flex-basis: 4rem;" >
          <h3>Header 1</h3>
          <p>a</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="category"style="flex-basis: 4rem;" >
          <h3>Header 2</h3>
           <p>a</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="category"style="flex-basis: 4rem;"> 
          <h3>Header 3</h3>
          <p>a</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you modified the flexibility of the flex property by setting a flex: column property using media queries. This is currently affecting the resized display you are getting.

Remove the flex property added in the media queries and it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I did this and it worked. I'm trying to make the layout turn into the two column layout "earlier" and before the text hits the edge of the box. Do you know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: @SusanB. could you be a little explicit so I can better understand?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I'm not really sure how to explain it, so here's a theoretical example for this. Right now, the three column layout turns into a two column layout when the screen is 700 pixels wide. I want the three column layout to turn into the two column layout when the screen is 1200 pixels wide. I tried changing the media query max-width numbers, but it didn't work. I "fixed" it with using white-space: nowrap and putting &ensp by the text in the boxes, but I don't think that what I did is a good way.

Comment: @SusanB. A better option would be to change the max-width of your wrapper element. it is currently set to 40%. you can change to a lease value and that should fix the issue. Let me know if there's still any issue.

Comment: @SusanB. so sorry for the trouble, i meant to type "lesser" value.